# How to center an entire webpage and position 4 divs side by side with only CSS3 and without BOOTSTRAP

Tags: html, css

I have this situation for a academic interview. It's a challenge and instead of spinning my wheels, for monday's final interview, I need help.

I have the following givens:

1. HTML PAGE that I cannot touch
2. CSS file where I do everything
3. An image that represents what the final product needs to be

Now, I'm not asking anyone to do this for me, but rather guide me to complete the task like I would if we were at work collaborating. Help me to think and pair program.

This is a finalist interview that I've been selected for academia.  It would be a swan song for my career... but I want to show them that I can reach out for help and work together vice sit there guessing and struggling.

Here's the image: [image]

Here's the HTML that cannot be touched:

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>The HTML</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>

  <body>

      <!-- page BEGIN -->
      <div class="page-wrapper">

        <!-- header BEGIN -->
        <div class="page-header-wrapper wrapper">
            <header class="page-header inner">
                <nav class="main-nav">
                    <ul class="main-nav-menu menu">
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a class="menu-link active-path" href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a class="menu-link" href="/">News</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a class="menu-link" href="/">Features</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a class="menu-link" href="/">Events</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a class="menu-link" href="/">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a class="menu-link" href="/">About</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
        <!-- header END -->

      <!-- content BEGIN -->
      <main class="content">

          <!-- top feature BEGIN -->
          <div class="top-feature-wrapper wrapper">
              <section class="top-feature inner">
                  <header class="top-feature-header">
                      <h1>Top Feature</h1>
                  </header>
                  <article>
                      <img class="top-feature-image" src="img/top-feature.png" alt="Top feature placeholder image">
                      <header class="top-feature-story-header">
                          <h2>Some text goes here...and here...and here</h2>
                          <h3>By the great people of...</h3>
                      </header>
                  </article>
              </section>
          </div>
          <!-- top feature END -->

        <!-- featured stories BEGIN -->
        <div class="featured-stories-wrapper wrapper">
            <section class="featured-stories inner">
                <header class="featured-stories-header">
                    <h1>Featured<br> Stories</h1>
                </header>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <article class="featured-story">
                            <img class="featured-story-image" src="img/feature.png" alt="Featured story placeholder image">
                            <span class="story-type">Feature</span>
                            <header class="featured-story-header">
                                <h2>Earth Week events begin next week</h2>
                                <h3>Some text goes here... </h3>
                            </header>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <article class="featured-story">
                            <img class="featured-story-image" src="img/feature.png" alt="Featured story placeholder image">
                            <span class="story-type">Photo Collection</span>
                            <header class="featured-story-header">
                                <h2>Photo: 'Big Data' kickoff</h2>
                                <h3>Some text goes here... </h3>
                            </header>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <article class="featured-story">
                            <img class="featured-story-image" src="img/feature.png" alt="Featured story placeholder image">
                            <span class="story-type">Feature</span>
                            <header class="featured-story-header">
                                <h2>Holocaust Survivor to Speak</h2>
                                <h3>Some text goes here... </h3>
                            </header>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <article class="featured-story">
                            <img class="featured-story-image" src="img/feature.png" alt="Featured story placeholder image">
                            <span class="story-type">Photo Collection</span>
                            <header class="featured-story-header">
                                <h2>'Beautiful Terror' on display through April 22</h2>
                                <h3>Some text goes here... </h3>
                            </header>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </div>
        <!-- featured stories END -->

      </main>
      <!-- content END -->

    </div>
    <!-- page END -->

  </body>

</html>
```

And now the CSS file that I've been working on.

```
@charset "utf-8";

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-weight: 100;
}
/* headings */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    line-height: 1.4em;
    margin: 20px 0 .4em;
    color: #000;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
}
/* Main Settings/RESET */
html, body, address, blockquote, div, dl, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ol, p, pre, table, ul,
dd, dt, li, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, tr, button, del, ins, map, object,
a, abbr, acronym, b, bdo, big, br, cite, code, dfn, em, i, img, kbd, q, samp, small, span,
strong, sub, sup, tt, var, legend, fieldset {
    /* This disables text size adjustment on iPhone */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* Set HTML5 elements to BLOCK */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

/* NAVBAR */
.main-nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    height:38px;
}
.main-nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.main-nav li {
    margin: 0px;
}
.main-nav li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #003f87;
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left
}
.main-nav li a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #35af3b;
}


/************************************************************************************
GENERAL STYLING
*************************************************************************************/
body {
    background: #fff;
    font: 1.05em/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #cccccc;
}
a {
    color: #026acb;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: #c6db01;
}
p {
    margin: 0 0 1.2em;
    padding: 0;
}
/* DIV STRUCTURE */

.page-wrapper > .page-header-wrapper {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

div .top-feature-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
div .top-feature-story-header {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
div .top-feature-image {
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}
div .featured-stories-wrapper .featured-stories {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
div .top-feature-wrapper h1 {
    font-size: 42px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #003f87;
}
div .featured-stories-wrapper h1 {
    font-size: 42px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #003f87;
}
div .featured-stories ul {
    list-style: none;
}

/* HEADERS */
header h2 {
    top: -30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #0097de;
    line-height: 35pt;
    width: 750px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #fff;
}
header h3 {
    top: -30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #003f87;
    line-height: 35pt;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #fff;
}
/* list */
ul, ol {
    margin: 1em 0 1.4em 24px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 140%;
}
li {
    margin: 0 0 .5em 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/************************************************************************************
STRUCTURE
*************************************************************************************/
.page-wrapper {
    border-top: #003f87 solid 10px;
}



/************************************************************************************
HEADER
*************************************************************************************/
header {
    position: relative;
}


/* Active Link */
.main-nav .menu-link.active-path {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #35af3b;
}

/* Flexible Images */
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}

/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {

    #header {
        height: auto;
    }

    page-header-wrapper {
        height: auto;
    }

    #main-nav {
        position: static;
    }

    #site-description {
        margin: 0 0 15px;
        position: static;
    }

    #content {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        margin: 20px 0;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    html {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    }

    #main-nav a {
        font-size: 90%;
        padding: 10px 8px;
    }

}
```

The CSS I was given was up to this comment:

```
/* Main Settings/RESET */
```

Here's the problem...

When you run this, and you'll need normalize.min.css... everything is PULLED TO THE LEFT.  I have tried like heck to center the page-wrapper using the obvious code:

```
max-width: 1920px; --the width of the image
margin: 0 auto;
```

But it will not move!

So, I'm seeking not the solution, per se, but collab to help me "see" the solution. Force me to work the problem as you would and I'll post UPDATE 1, UPDATE 2, etc...

Thank you everyone and I will acknowledge Stackoverflow's assistance at my finalist interview at 1PM PDT.  This has to go with me, and I'll need to explain the CSS as well.

Help me work the problem and allow me to LEARN.

**OF NOTE: They recommend using SASS or LESS, but it's not required. Perhaps therein lies the "solution".**

UPDATE 1:  Solution for center is:

```
body {
    background: #fff;
    font: 1.05em/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #cccccc;
    /* Added the following which WORKED! */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

UPDATE 2:

This solution from Adrian works correctly as well.

```
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPjeRE
```

I've tried both:  Each has it's benefits... with VXp's, which I like immediately, it was quick and just looks great.  Only issue and this is not a roadblock, but the blue strip across the top, no longer extends full with of the browser.  Again, it's a non-issue...and will not hurt me.

The only issue with Adrian's is that when I placed the code in my code here on my machine, the menu dropped to a SIDEBAR menu, list style but with no bullets.

It actually look cool! I need to vote for both of you because both of your solutions work well and I will acknowledge.

Secondly, I need to adjust the FEATURE stories so that they are side-by-side and I used list-style: none; but they remain, the way they look.

I know that list-style moves ul's to side-by-side but I need to understand CSS Specificity.  I'm using ALL CLASSES and elements to isolate which is needed.  This is a real challenge to understand.

I know that ID's take priority, elements are next then classes.

I truly appreciate everyone's help...  Oh, another answer just came in. I'll save this and look.

UPDATE 3: SUCCESS!!! Now for the responsiveness factor...

EVERYONE! Please see the completed CSS and give it a try.  With help from Adrian and VXp, I've been successful.

BUT the following **roadblocks** remain:

**1. The bottom GRAY does NOT extend left and right
 2. The page is NOT responsive and again, I cannot use BOOTSTRAP and cannot touch the HTML code at all. 
 3. I've incorporated FLEXBOX and find it is working, but... nothing is responsive. That is my final roadblock.**

I've fixed the bottom FEATURED STORIES section from research from Adrian and VXp's solutions.

NOW; the main.css solution thus far:

```
@charset "utf-8";

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-weight: 100;
}
/* headings */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    line-height: 1.4em;
    margin: 20px 0 .4em;
    color: #000;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
}
/* Main Settings/RESET */
html, body, address, blockquote, div, dl, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ol, p, pre, table, ul,
dd, dt, li, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, tr, button, del, ins, map, object,
a, abbr, acronym, b, bdo, big, br, cite, code, dfn, em, i, img, kbd, q, samp, small, span,
strong, sub, sup, tt, var, legend, fieldset {
    /* This disables text size adjustment on iPhone */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* Set HTML5 elements to BLOCK */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

/* NAVBAR */
.main-nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 43px;
}
.main-nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.main-nav li {
    margin: 0px;
}
.main-nav li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #003f87;
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left
}
.main-nav li a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #35af3b;
}


/************************************************************************************
GENERAL STYLING
*************************************************************************************/
body {
    background: #fff;
    font: 1.05em/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #cccccc;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-top: #003f87 solid 10px;
}
a {
    color: #026acb;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: #c6db01;
}
p {
    margin: 0 0 1.2em;
    padding: 0;
}
/* DIV STRUCTURE */
/* Added on 9302017 */

div .featured-stories-wrapper {

}



/* Added on 9292017 */
div .top-feature-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
div .top-feature-story-header h2 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #0097de;
    width: 750px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
div .top-feature-story-header h3 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #003f87;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 20px;
}


div .top-feature-image {
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}
/* Featured Stories */
div .featured-stories-wrapper {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
div .top-feature-wrapper h1 {
    font-size: 42px;
    background-color: #c6db02;
    color: #003f87;
    width: 400px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 5% 50%, 0% 0%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 5% 50%, 0% 0%);
}
div .featured-stories-wrapper h1 {
    font-size: 42px; 
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #003f87;
}
header.featured-story-header h2 {
    width: 210px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 22px;
}
header.featured-story-header h3 {
    width: 215px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 16px;
}



/* span for GREEN POLYGON */
span.story-type {
    position:relative;
    top: -36px;
    margin-left: -18px;
    background-color: #c6db02;
    color: #003f87;
    text-align:right;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 10% 50%, 0% 0%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 10% 50%, 0% 0%);
}

div .featured-stories ul {
    list-style: none;
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 38px;
    width: 1050px;
}
div .featured-stories ul li {
    width: 200px;
}
/************************************************************************************
FEATURED STORIES
*************************************************************************************/




/* HEADERS */
header h2 {
    top: -30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    line-height: 35pt;
}
header h3 {
    top: -30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    line-height: 35pt;
}
/* list */
ul, ol {
    margin: 1em 0 1.4em 24px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 140%;
}
li {
    margin: 0 0 .5em 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/************************************************************************************
STRUCTURE
*************************************************************************************/



/************************************************************************************
HEADER
*************************************************************************************/
header {
    position: relative;
}


/* Active Link */
.main-nav .menu-link.active-path {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #35af3b;
}

/* Flexible Images */
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}

/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {

    header {
        height: auto;
    }
    .page-wrapper {
        width: 980px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .page-header-wrapper {
        height: auto;
    }

    .main-nav {
        position: static;
    }

    .featured-stories-wrapper {
        margin: 0 0 15px;
        position: static;
    }

    .content {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        margin: 20px 0;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    html {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    }

    #main-nav a {
        font-size: 90%;
        padding: 10px 8px;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your monitor is full HD and setting the page to its full width doesn't seem to work for you. Set the wrapper to smaller width, like this:

```
    /************************************************************************************
        STRUCTURE
*************************************************************************************/
        body {
          border-top: #003f87 solid 10px;
        }

        .page-wrapper {
          width: 1260px;
            margin:auto;
        }
```

The only difference would be, that you have to move border-top to Body element for it to cover full screen.

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPjeRE

**edit**:
Some extra code to help you with your further tasks:

```
/************************************************************************************
STRUCTURE
*************************************************************************************/
body { border-top: #003f87 solid 10px;}
.page-wrapper {width: 1260px; margin:auto;}
.featured-story {width: 22%; float:left; margin:1%; border: 1px dashed #f00; }
.featured-story h2, .featured-story h3 {width: auto; font-size: 15px; line-height: 25px; background: none;color: black;  }
.featured-story h2 {font-weight: bold;}
.featured-story h3 {font-style:normal;}
```

DEMO: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXrvmV?editors=1100

Comment: Adrian, I like this, but the first one, works best, although your solution is a correct solution as well. The only problem I have now, is that the border, using VXp's solution, does not extend full with. The 10px BLUE STRIP at the top.  So I like both yours and VXp's solution. How do I vote for both?

Comment: By they way, the other solution uses completely different positioning. (FLEX)

Make sure you covered this topic during your course, otherwise your teacher may be suspicious ;)

Some more info on the topic:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Adrian, you and VXp are great! THANK YOU. Actually, I will be part of the IT department at the school (higher ed).  I'm still learning even though I've been in IT for over 25 years.  I truly appreciate you and your assistance.  I wish I could make the SOLUTION for both of you. So, I can use the FLEX BOX for adjusting the FEATURED STORIES, right?

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I mixed up the intro and thought you are a student. You can learn how to "flex" and do it this way or the "tradictional" way with floating divs. Both ways will lead to the same results.

Gonna update the answer with another proposal (this time for featured stories ;))

Answer (score 1):

You can use the power of flexbox on the parent to make the magic happen.

```
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Since the div.page-wrapper is the only direct child of the parent body, this works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I see other users are addressing solutions to your problem. I wanted to stress this point that you tried:

> I have tried like heck to center the page-wrapper using the obvious
>   code:
>
> `max-width: 1920px; --the width of the image margin: 0 auto;` But it
>   will not move!

You have a good point, but the wrong target and the wrong size. The `page-wrapper` div is covering the whole width of the viewport, so you can't center it. You can center it's children, there's a `.content` div that wraps all the content (but the header). You can center it using the margin technique you tried:

```
.content {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You need to set a `width` or `max-width` smaller than the viewport width, and set both `margins` *left* and *right* to **auto**. You can use both `width` and `max-width` to keep it responsive:

```
.content {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

*Remember that it only works to center block elements.*

So here's the snippet with `.content` as showed before:

```css
@charset "utf-8";

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-weight: 100;
}
/* headings */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    line-height: 1.4em;
    margin: 20px 0 .4em;
    color: #000;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
}
/* Main Settings/RESET */
html, body, address, blockquote, div, dl, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ol, p, pre, table, ul,
dd, dt, li, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, tr, button, del, ins, map, object,
a, abbr, acronym, b, bdo, big, br, cite, code, dfn, em, i, img, kbd, q, samp, small, span,
strong, sub, sup, tt, var, legend, fieldset {
    /* This disables text size adjustment on iPhone */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* Set HTML5 elements to BLOCK */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

/* NAVBAR */
.main-nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    height:38px;
}
.main-nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.main-nav li {
    margin: 0px;
}
.main-nav li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #003f87;
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left
}
.main-nav li a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #35af3b;
}


/************************************************************************************
GENERAL STYLING
*************************************************************************************/
html,body {
    background: #fff;
    font: 1.05em/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #cccccc;
}
a {
    color: #026acb;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: #c6db01;
}
p {
    margin: 0 0 1.2em;
    padding: 0;
}
/* DIV STRUCTURE */

.content {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.page-wrapper > .page-header-wrapper {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

div .top-feature-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
div .top-feature-story-header {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
div .top-feature-image {
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}
div .featured-stories-wrapper .featured-stories {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
div .top-feature-wrapper h1 {
    font-size: 42px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #003f87;
}
div .featured-stories-wrapper h1 {
    font-size: 42px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #003f87;
}
div .featured-stories ul {
    list-style: none;
}

/* HEADERS */
header h2 {
    top: -30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #0097de;
    line-height: 35pt;
    width: 750px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #fff;
}
header h3 {
    top: -30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #003f87;
    line-height: 35pt;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #fff;
}
/* list */
ul, ol {
    margin: 1em 0 1.4em 24px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 140%;
}
li {
    margin: 0 0 .5em 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/************************************************************************************
STRUCTURE
*************************************************************************************/
.page-wrapper {
    border-top: #003f87 solid 10px;
}



/************************************************************************************
HEADER
*************************************************************************************/
header {
    position: relative;
}


/* Active Link */
.main-nav .menu-link.active-path {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #35af3b;
}

/* Flexible Images */
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}

/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {

    #header {
        height: auto;
    }

    page-header-wrapper {
        height: auto;
    }

    #main-nav {
        position: static;
    }

    #site-description {
        margin: 0 0 15px;
        position: static;
    }

    #content {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        margin: 20px 0;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    html {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    }

    #main-nav a {
        font-size: 90%;
        padding: 10px 8px;
    }

}
```

```html
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>The HTML</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css">
       <!-- Your css file
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"> 
       -->
    </head>

  <body>

      <!-- page BEGIN -->
      <div class="page-wrapper">

        <!-- header BEGIN -->
        <div class="page-header-wrapper wrapper">
            <header class="page-header inner">
                <nav class="main-nav">
                    <ul class="main-nav-menu menu">
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a class="menu-link active-path" href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a class="menu-link" href="/">News</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a class="menu-link" href="/">Features</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a class="menu-link" href="/">Events</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a class="menu-link" href="/">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a class="menu-link" href="/">About</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
        <!-- header END -->

      <!-- content BEGIN -->
      <main class="content">

          <!-- top feature BEGIN -->
          <div class="top-feature-wrapper wrapper">
              <section class="top-feature inner">
                  <header class="top-feature-header">
                      <h1>Top Feature</h1>
                  </header>
                  <article>
                      <img class="top-feature-image" src="https://placeimg.com/800/480/nature" alt="Top feature placeholder image">
                      <header class="top-feature-story-header">
                          <h2>Some text goes here...and here...and here</h2>
                          <h3>By the great people of...</h3>
                      </header>
                  </article>
              </section>
          </div>
          <!-- top feature END -->

        <!-- featured stories BEGIN -->
        <div class="featured-stories-wrapper wrapper">
            <section class="featured-stories inner">
                <header class="featured-stories-header">
                    <h1>Featured<br> Stories</h1>
                </header>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <article class="featured-story">
                            <img class="featured-story-image" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people" alt="Featured story placeholder image">
                            <span class="story-type">Feature</span>
                            <header class="featured-story-header">
                                <h2>Earth Week events begin next week</h2>
                                <h3>Some text goes here... </h3>
                            </header>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <article class="featured-story">
                            <img class="featured-story-image" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people" alt="Featured story placeholder image">
                            <span class="story-type">Photo Collection</span>
                            <header class="featured-story-header">
                                <h2>Photo: 'Big Data' kickoff</h2>
                                <h3>Some text goes here... </h3>
                            </header>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <article class="featured-story">
                            <img class="featured-story-image" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people" alt="Featured story placeholder image">
                            <span class="story-type">Feature</span>
                            <header class="featured-story-header">
                                <h2>Holocaust Survivor to Speak</h2>
                                <h3>Some text goes here... </h3>
                            </header>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <article class="featured-story">
                            <img class="featured-story-image" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people" alt="Featured story placeholder image">
                            <span class="story-type">Photo Collection</span>
                            <header class="featured-story-header">
                                <h2>'Beautiful Terror' on display through April 22</h2>
                                <h3>Some text goes here... </h3>
                            </header>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </div>
        <!-- featured stories END -->

      </main>
      <!-- content END -->

    </div>
    <!-- page END -->

  </body>

</html>
```

You can center the header too:

```
.content, .page-header-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Flexbox** is a good solution, but it lacks support in older browsers (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp), so it's good to cover both aproaches.

Comment: MarioZ - Thank you for this, sir. Very cool. Please see UPDATE 3 and apply it to your solution. I have 3 REMAINING ROADBLOCKS. I took the advice of Adrian and now you, by not using FLEXBOX, even though I stated I did.  The four boxes in the featured stories section now are correctly aligned. Woo Hoo!  I'm giving you a VOTE too for your solution.  Need to overcome the RESPONSIVENESS problem and I'm ready. Also, I'll be referencing this in my interview to show the panelists that I REACH OUT when I hit roadblocks vice spinning my wheels. EVERYONE will be credited with helping: YOU ARE MY TEAM!